# Rejecting some HTML tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, linux, bash, text, beautifulsoup

I know that it might be very simple, but I couldn't find the proper way to handle it.
I have a HTML document, which I want to extract its content. The body of the body of this document is:

```
<div class="articleContent">
        <div class="dateblock">
            <div class="textsize">
                <span class="textsize_label">
                    Font Size</span> <a href="javascript:decreaseFontSize();"
                        title="Increase font-size" class="txtsizeminus"><span>-</span></a> <a href="javascript:increaseFontSize();"
                            title="Increase font-size" class="txtsizeplus"><span>+</span></a>
            </div>

            <p class="article_date">
                Last Update: date
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cpAB_cp1_cbcContentBreak">
<div class="zoomMe">
        <P>The Content is here</p>
</div>
```

What I want is the content of the document not the other info like "Font Size" and "Last Update". But since all of these information are children of "articleContent", I don't know how to get rid of them.
I have to note that since these additional info might change from one document to another, I can not use simple regular expressions to remove them from the final strings. I have to filter them out while I'm processing the HTML file.
I have to add that I am using the following commands to extract this part of the document, and also its content:

```
body = soup.find("div", {"class":"articleContent"})
pars= [s for s in body.strings if s.strip() != '']
```

So, the question is how to avoid having those additional info in the "pars" array?

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just looking for the particular tag you want?

```
desired_div = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "zoomMe"})
print(desired_div.text)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the point is that I want to remove the following tags and their contents from the final output. The blacklist of tags is: <div class="textsize"> and <p class="article_date">

Comment: Ah. I didn't see your edit. I think I see what you are looking for. Some programmatic help (branching) should solve the problem.